# Running hive from cmd with string of settings not working ((...)+ loop did not match anything at character ''' error)

Tags: hadoop, cmd, hive, cloudera

i have the following query (tester.hql):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${hiveconf:schema}.${hiveconf:company}_${hiveconf:START_DT}_${hiveconf:END_DT}_${hiveconf:tablename};
CREATE TABLE ${hiveconf:schema}.${hiveconf:company}_${hiveconf:START_DT}_${hiveconf:END_DT}_${hiveconf:tablename}

AS
SELECT

company, 
sum(amount) as total 

from table
where date between  ${hiveconf:START_DT} and ${hiveconf:END_DT}
group by company
```

i want to be able to run this WITH a string containing the settings so i do:

```
hive -i <(echo "SET START_DT = '201804';SET END_DT = '201806';SET schema = asia;SET company = amazon;SET tablename = test;") -f tester.hql
```

but i get this error:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-log4j.properties
FAILED: ParseException line 3:50 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character '''
```

how can i run this as i would like?

Comment: You set `START_DT = '201804'`, shouldnt be a proper MMddyyyy formatted string?

Comment: no the dates have the above format

Comment: so i do not think they are dates but a string. could you please first just try to display your parameters like  `SELECT ${hiveconf:START_DT} and ${hiveconf:END_DT} ` - just to check if all parameters are passed correctly. I think some parameters are missing and passing null values.

Comment: does it works using hive --hiveconf ... variables?